# scroll event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Setch.me](http://setch.me) loading normally on desktop but not trigerring on mobile unless if I click on photographers/makeup artists, I've added height=device-height after searching for a solution here but that didn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
        track_page++; 
        load_contents(track_page); 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery live scroll event on mobile (work around)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753367/jquery-live-scroll-event-on-mobile-work-around)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Try this:

```
$(document.body).on('touchmove', onScroll); // for mobile
$(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 

// callback
function onScroll(){ 
    if( $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight ) { 
        track_page++; 
        load_contents(track_page); 
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked, thank you so much, so the second one detects any kind of scrolling even if it's not to the end of the document?

Comment: @Krim - any touch move means what it means :) it triggers the callback on when a finger is moving on the screen, and scroll can be a by-product of that.

Comment: it works for me with  document.body.scrollHeight-100 extra space! thx!

Comment: On mobile, any touch move (moving up, moving down) also calls the function!

Answer (score 6):

```js
var addition_constant = 0;
$(document.body).on('touchmove', onScroll); // for mobile
$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll() {
  var addition = ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);

  var scrollHeight = (document.body.scrollHeight - 1);
  if (addition > scrollHeight && addition_constant < addition) {

    addition_constant = addition;

    loadmorecontest();
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou bro.. window.innerHeight worked awesome for me..

Comment: It's working for me, I have checked in my mobile chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

The "scrollTop" value must be rounded on mobile devices using "Math.ceil". (It's decimal based on the resolution of the screen), so:

```
if (el.scrollHeight <= Math.ceil(el.scrollTop) + el.offsetHeight) {
    // so something...
}
```

Comment: My conditional statement was like the ones above but the rounding fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous comments, `$(window).scrollTop()`
seems not to work on mobile and should be replaced with `document.body.scrollTop`

Answer (score 0):

It seems bit irrelevant but since I found myself here and my reason that it not worked is the element that I was trying to scroll has;

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

When I remove that it worked perfectly. I just wrote that for if it is also someone's case.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you didn't close correctly your event, this should be like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
    track_page++; 
    load_contents(track_page); 
}});
```

Comment: it's not the *event* which he didn't "close" but the callback function.